# How can I model 3 entities with unique constraints and their relationships?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have 3 entity classes. They are "Game", "GameDescription", "Language".
A game can have many descriptions, but there can be at most one description with a language. For example, a game can have 2 descriptions, one in English, one in French. This game can only have one English description, the others can be in other languages. How can I model this in my Spring Boot project with Spring Data and JPA?

### Game

id / name / gameDescriptions

### GameDescription

id / game_id / language_id / text

### Language

id / name

I tried OneToMany relationship between Game & GameDescription entities, and ManyToOne relationship between GameDescription & Language entities to do the mapping among those 3 entities. But it does not provide the required outcome.

Game Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GAME")
public class Game {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game")
    private List<GameDescription> descriptions;

    // getters and setters
 }
```

GameDescription Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GAME_DESCRIPTION")
public class GameDescription {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GAME_ID")
    private Game game;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "LANG_ID")
    private Language language;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Language Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LANGUAGE")
public class Language {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "LOCAL_NAME")
    private String localName;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I need those 3 entities finely structured as there should be only one description of a game per language. For example, I expect a game with descriptions in 5 different languages.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you're trying to generate tables based on your entities and you want the constraints  to be defined properly? Because leaving the constraints aside, this setup looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a composite primary key using `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId`. You have to modify the `GameDescription` entity for this and create a new class with `@Embeddable` annotation. Something like this

```
@Embeddable
public class GameDescriptionId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GAME_ID")
    private Game game;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
    CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "LANG_ID")
    private Language language;
    // getters, setters, override equals and hashcode
}
```

Then modify the `GameDescription` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GAME_DESCRIPTION")
public class GameDescription {

    @EmbeddedId
    private GameDescriptionId id;
    private String text;
    // getters setters

}
```

You can read more about here https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/